# Is there a way to access paper_trail_options in a custom adapter for paper trail gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I would like to use paper trail to track when users change a sensitive field, like a password. This isn't a built-in option with paper trail right now, so I was hoping to add a custom adapter that approximates this behavior. I would like to add a `hide` option to the has_paper_trail in the model, similar to `ignore` and `skip`, except when a hidden field is changed a new version is still created. `object_changes` will have something like "password": ["modified"], instead of "password": ["password1", "password2"].

I was hoping to do this using a custom adapter and modifying the `diff` method.

I have deleted the 'object' column from the table so that the sensitive information will not be stored that, and I have set up the config to use my custom adapter. I'm struggling to access fields marked as hidden from the custom adapter though.

In the model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail hide: [:password]
```

And in the custom adapter:

```rb
  def diff(changes)
    diff_changes = {}
    # How to get this?
    hidden_fields = PaperTrail.record.paper_trail_options[:hide]
    changes.each do |field, value_changes|
      if hidden_fields.contains(field)
        diff_changes[field] = "modified"
      else
        diff_changes[field] = value_changes
      end
    end
    diff_changes
  end
```

I can't figure out how to access paper_trail_options from here- is the custom adaptor strategy just not viable, or is there a way I can get the hidden fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass whatever you want to your adapter's constructor.

```rb
PaperTrail.config.object_changes_adapter = MyObjectChangesAdapter.new(
  'User' => { hide: [:password] }
)
```

Or make it a constant.

```rb
class MyObjectChangesAdapter
  CONFIG = {
    'User' => { hide: [:password] }
  }
```

Just some ideas, there's no convention for this. `object_changes_adapter` is a feature for expert users only.

Good question. Nice to see people using the adapter feature.